# Esconder/Mostrar uma navbar de acordo com a rolagem

Tags: javascript, rolamento

Seguinte amigos, tenho esse código:

//Função que esconde/mostra a subnavbar de acordo com a rolagem

```
$('#view-2').scroll(function() {
  var topo = $(this).scrollTop(); // = 0
    if (topo > 0){
        $('.subnavbar').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.subnavbar').fadeIn();
    }
    console.log(topo);
 });
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas queria fazer com que, com uma rolagem para cima (scrollUp), aparecesse novamente a navbar?

Poderiam me ajudar com a lógica e a solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fácil amigo é só colocar o código assim:

```
anterior = 0;
$('#view-2').scroll(function() {
  var topo = $(this).scrollTop(); // = 0

    if (topo > 0){
        if(topo < anterior){
           $('.subnavbar').fadeIn();
        }else{
           $('.subnavbar').fadeOut();
        }
    } else {
      $('.subnavbar').fadeIn();
    }

    anterior = topo; 
    console.log(topo);
 });
```

**Explicação:**

Basicamente o que você precisa fazer é definir uma variavel global chamada anterior, que é o valor anterior do top na `scrollagem`, e ai toda vez que o top muda o valor anterior é salvo, e você verifica se o top é menor que o anterior, então mostra a `subnavbar`

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Obrigado!